# ASP.NET Get bytes of application/pdf attachment

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rotativa

I have this url: https://example.com/getPDF/Index

This method returns an attached application/pdf via Rotativa

```
public ActionResult RedBluePDF(string community, string procedure) 
{ 
     var model = new GeneratePDFModel(); 
     return new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf("GeneratePDF", model){
          FileName = "TestViewAsPdf.pdf"
     }
}
```

My Question is how would I call this method and get the bytes from application/pdf file? I do not want to generate the PDF and get the BuildFile method provided by Rotativa to get the bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you should be able to call `BuildFile` on the output from `ViewAsPdf`, like this:

```
public ActionResult RedBluePDF(string community, string procedure) 
{ 
   var model = new GeneratePDFModel(); 
   var pdf= new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf("GeneratePDF", model){
        FileName = "TestViewAsPdf.pdf"
   }
   var bytes = pdf.BuildFile(); // byte array
   // do what you want with the byte array here
}
```

Comment: I do not want to use BuildFile, it does not work on my server.

Answer (score 0):

If `BuildFile()` is not working, then try `BuildPdf()` as follows,

```
public ActionResult RedBluePDF(string community, string procedure) 
{ 
     var model = new GeneratePDFModel(); 

      var pdf= new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf("GeneratePDF", model){
        FileName = "TestViewAsPdf.pdf"
   }

  var bytes = pdf.BuildPdf(ControllerContext);
}
```